# Is Multi-Tenancy the correct approach where there is interactivity

Tags: social-networking, multi-tenant

I'm working on a project that is set up as multi-tenant, separate users, data stores, etc. However, as I look further into different scenarios, I see things that may not mix well with multi-tenancy, or at least as I understand it.

**Tenants can be hierarchal**

- Company A

  - West Region
  - East Region
- Company B

  - Campus A
  - Campus B
- Company C

**Tenants can provide resources to another resource**

- Company A creates a resource
- Company A shares it with Company B with specified permissions
- Company C shares a resource with Company B
- Company B can now use resources provided by Company A and C

I'm not tied to multi-tenancy, but I want to make sure that whatever pattern I choose, I am following the best practices of the pattern.

Is hierarchal multi-tenancy defined well enough to actually attempt? I don't see much online about it, except for a proposed Open Stack project and a research paper in only 2014. I could potentially use hierarchal users instead, but there are, of course, other benefits to tenants.

Now given that I want tenants to be able to share resources, in any direction, maybe I don't need hierarchal tenants. Maybe a need a normal flat multi-tenant pattern with just an added layer of sharing. One tenant would share to another tenant or maybe a user in another tenant.

In the latter, each user seems like they become their own tenant, with their own data. It seems like it is more and more like a social network. in Facebook, I can share things to others, they can share things to me, there is no direct hierarchy, but brands will make pages that reflect the idea of a hierarchy, without actually having one. For instance, Microsoft has Microsoft, but also Xbox, Xbox Support 1, Xbox Support 7, Windows, Bing, etc.

So I've started here with a multi-tenant architecture in front of me and now I'm thing a business grade "social network" is what I really need.

Do either of those tracks make sense? Any thing you would have me change or consider?

Answer (score 0):

In cloud computing, multi-tenancy (MT) is commonly accompanied by tenant isolation.  If we take the Wikipedia definition, MT is independent of sharing.

In an MT architecture, one instance of a software serves multiple tenants (or groups of users).  This is in contrast to multi-instance software in which multiple instances of a software serves multiple tenants.

The main benefit of the MT architecture is of cost - software updates can be done on the single instance to benefit all of the tenants.  MT software provides a common base of functionality for tenants, but commonly have interfaces that allow each tenant to customize branding & workflows.

Your project looks to be MT with sharing capability.  Let's assume each Company wants to be able to share access to some resources.  The architecture then should have sufficient flexibility for the tenant to be able to control access to resources.  The underlying frameworks should be fast, secure, and reliable, and auditable.

Since your focus is on sharing flexibility, it's important that the architecture supports letting tenants define access to resources the way you and they want - tenant to tenant, or tenant to some user.

In my opinion, I would consider starting with a "default-deny" architecture - one that doesn't share anything by default, and allow the tenants to setup rules for access to resources.

Short version: Multi-tenancy is generally independent of interactivity.